# How to insert a DIV element with Facebook ID attribute using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert a DIV with an ID attribute (Javascript) into a facebook page.

```
element.innerHTML="<div>Test</div> --> Works!
element.innerHTML="<div id="container">Test</div> -->It does not work!
```

Can someone explain to me why I can not put the ID attribute in the DIV?. Thank you.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. It's `element.innerHTML= '<div id="container">Test</div>'`

Comment: you closed your open double quote with another double quote... mix with single quote so do you don't quote yourself out

Comment: Thank you all !!!!!!!! I had already tried everything and I did not know what to do, I thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

What I observe is your div doesn't have closing quote as pointed out by other users in comment section. I have update the innerHTML(with id as well as without id).

Please use `""` inside `''` or `''` inside `""`. Don't try to mix them as it will break the syntax.

```js
var element1 = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
element1.innerHTML="<div>Test</div>";// --> Works!
var element2 = document.getElementById('otherDiv');
element2.innerHTML='<div id="container">Div with Id</div>';
```

```html
<div id='parentDiv'></div>
<div id='otherDiv'></div>
```